# Change of measure from physical to risk-neutral under Radon-Nikodym and Girsanov Theorem

Tags: stochastic-calculus, risk-neutral-measure, girsanov

Given a stochastic process, how do we prove and generate the change-of-measure?
I have been trying to prove the change-of-measure as under the Radon-Nikodym theorem and Girsanov Theorem, but struggling.

I read through the thread here : [Radon-Nikodym derivative and risk natural measure](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16605/radon-nikodym-derivative-and-risk-natural-measure) as well.

Given a lognormal process : [image]

which is under the real-world measure.

We claim there is an equivalent probability measure (called the risk-neutral measure) where the return is the risk-free rate, with the Brownian Motion adjusted with a drift.

We set this equation to be : [image]

1. So we have set the 'market-price of risk' $= (\mu - r)/\sigma$
2. We set the risk-neutral Brownian motion $dW(Q) = (\mu - r)/\sigma * dt + dW$

My understanding of the Radon-Nikodym and Girsanov Theorem, is that we can now express any asset X (or S in this case) from one measure (real-world) into another measure (risk-neutral) by the Radon-Nikodym as per follows

1. Given 
   [image]

where EN is the expectation under risk-neutral world, X is asset X, EU is expectation under real-world' and dN/dU is the Radon-Nikodym derivative

2. Is the term dN/dU merely the expectation of the stochastic exponential
   [image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: question is, do I have the Radon-Nikodym derivative correct (2) according to the convention?